# Program that displays hours and minutes with 15 extra minutes added to them

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to write a program which reads hours and minutes in the 24-hour clock format and as an output I need to have the hour and minutes in `hh:mm` format with 15 extra minutes added to them.

For example lets say :
I type in `23:59` the output should read `0:14`.

**Note:** Hours should always be between the 0 and 23-digit range and minutes should always be in the 0 to 59 digit range.Hours should always print themselves with one (or two digits if needed), as for the minutes they must print themselves with two digits.

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: I agree, you need to write a program. There is no question in here.

Comment: well, in the begging I thought that maybe I could use the LocalTime class and the addminutes function but since I am very new to programming I couldn't get my head around how to properly format it all and then I thoutht maybe I could use the if statemnt and I stumbled across three formulas which were supposed to help me out with my calculations(var totalMin = minutes + 15; var totalHour = hour + totalMin / 60;var minutesAfterHour = totalMin % 60) but all in all I am stuck and been stcuk for a whole day now. This was my attempt using the LocalTime class - https://pastebin.com/c70LVS1N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it by steps

1. Read user input, with `Scanner`
2. Build a `LocaleTime` with the input, usng a formatter
3. add 15min to this time
4. print this time

---

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.nextLine();
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
time = time.plusMinutes(15);
System.out.println(time);
```

Comment: Helping a bit much for my taste, otherwise nice advice. To print the hours with 1 digit I believe you need to format using a formatter with format pattern string `H:mm`.

Comment: thank you so much,you made it look so easy!Now I have an understaning of how to format a string into time class!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use normal if/else like this. I havent tried all cases in my code and left for you to work on it .

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
 String time = "23:40";

 int hours = Integer.parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);
 int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time.split(":")[1]);
 int extra_min =0;
 if ( minutes >45)
 {
     if (hours<23) 
     {
         hours = hours+1; 
     }
     else
         hours = 00;

     extra_min = (15+minutes)-60;
     minutes = extra_min;
 }
 else
 { 
     if( hours ==23)
     {
         hours = 0;
         minutes = minutes+15;
     }
     else{
     minutes = minutes+15;
     hours = hours +1;
     }
 }

System.out.println(hours+":"+minutes);
```

}

Comment: `23:40` >> `24:55` hum

Comment: Thank you so much!I will check it out!

Comment: @azro - thanks for pointing out . have corrected the same for that particular case . there might be few more :P